# Did the Double Asteroid Redirection Test (DART) trigger an answer for the Fermi paradox?

Tags: general-relativity, astronomy, collision

The successful implementation of the Double Asteroid Redirection Test (DART - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Asteroid_Redirection_Test) was an awesome feat of engineering.

However, hypothetically speaking here, if we assume there is a higher level of intelligence within our galaxy/universe then there would be a chance that they have mapped all the known comets etc.

Does this then raise the question of the Fermi paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) as we have just signalled that another intelligent form of life exists.

Would they pick up that we have altered the course of an asteriod via DART?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely. We've done so many more conspicuous things. Nuclear explosions, artificial light, radio broadcasts, agriculture, atmospheric modification, ...